# event.currentTarget.getAttribute() doesn't work in Firefox - event is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla

I have function

```
function someFunction(event) {
    var dataP = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("some-attribute");
}
```

and only in Firefox I got error that "Event is undefined".

What can I do about this problem?

Comment: You have to pass it explecitely from callback event to function handler, FF doesn't use global event model. So provide relevant code binding handler

Comment: Can you please explain more precisely, I'm not sure I understand you well?

Comment: Again, provide relevant code you use to bind event which calls this method and so we could help

Answer (score 1):

I changed the way of getting this attribute value like this

```
var dataP = document.getElementById("element-id").getAttribute("some-attribute")
```

and it works.